# Limit of a sequence of functions of a sequence of reals

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, sequence-of-function

Let $C \subset \mathbb{R}$ be a compact set. Let $f$ be a function $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow C$ which is continuous in $x_0$, and an $\varepsilon$-interval around it, $x_n$ a sequence of numbers s.t. $\lim_{n}{x_n}=x_0$, and $f_n: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow C$ a sequence of functions s.t. $\forall x \in \mathbb{R} \ \lim_{n}{f_n(x)}=f(x)$. Note: $f_n$ are not necessarily continuous in $x_0$.

I can prove that

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}{f_n(x_n)}=f(x_0)
$$

using continuity + chaining:

$ |f_n(x_n) - f(x_0)| \leq |f_n(x_n) - f(x_n) + f(x_n) - f(x_0)| \overset{Trianlge}{\leq} |f_n(x_n) - f(x_n)| + |f(x_n) - f(x_0)| \leq \varepsilon_1 +  \varepsilon_2$

where $\varepsilon_1$ is due to <s>point-wise</s> uniform convergence and $\varepsilon_2$ due to continuity of $f$ around $x_0$. I'm specifically omitting a lot of details here as I'm not interested in the correctness of the proof itself. E.g., I still have to figure out uniform convergence.

I have a few questions regarding $\lim_{n \to \infty}{f_n(x_n)}$

- Can it be computed as $\lim_{m \to \infty}\lim_{n \to \infty}{f_n(x_m)}$? Note $f_n$ is not necessarily continuous, but $\lim_n(f_n)$ is continous in an epsilon ball around  $x_0$.
- Is the above question related to the Moore-Osgood Theorem? How does the uniform convergence in the latter relate to my setup?

  - answered in the comments: my proof would not work without it
- What are the conditions for $\lim_{n \to \infty}\lim_{m \to \infty}{f_n(x_m)} = \lim_{m \to \infty}\lim_{n \to \infty}{f_n(x_m)} = \lim_{n \to \infty}{f_n(x_n)}$ in general?

Comment: Why is $\lim_n f_n$ continuous in a ball around $x_0$? For example, consider a function $f$ which is continuous only at one point $x_0$ and take $f_n := f$ for all $n \in \Bbb N$. Then, $\lim_n f_n = f$ is only continuous at $x_0$.

Comment: In your situation $\lim_{m \to \infty}\lim_{n \to \infty}{f_n(x_m)} = \lim_{m \to \infty}f(x_m) = f(x_0)$.

Comment: Although you don't care, I want to point out that $\lim f_n(x_n)$ can be anything and might not exists: e.g. let $f$ be identically zero, $x_n = 1/n$ and $f_n $ be everywhere zero except at $1/n$ where $f(1/n) = a_n$. Then $f_n$ converges pointwisely to $f$ but $f_n(1/n) =a_n$....

Comment: And to give the other iterated limit, that is not true. Consider the indicator functions $f_n := \chi_{(0, 1/n]}$. Then $f_n$ converges pointwise to the zero function $=: f$. Consider the sequence $x_n = 1/n$ converging to $x_0 := 0$. Then, for each $n \in \Bbb N$, we see that $\lim_{m \to \infty} f_n(x_m) = 1$ and thus, $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\lim_{m \to \infty} f_n(x_m) = 1 \neq f(0).$$

Comment: As @ArcticChar has pointed out, your proof is incorrect. You can't write $|f_n(x_n) - f(x_n)| < \varepsilon_1$ using pointwise convergence because the "$n$" also appears in the argument of the functions.

Comment: @AryamanMaithani I see. Would a uniform convergence of $f_n$ allow me to use $|f_n(x_n) - f(x_n)| < \varepsilon_1 $?

Comment: @AryamanMaithani, ok, fair enough. Sorry, I'm trying to reduce a complex problem to subproblems, and eventually ended up posting a too general statement. My function is continuous almost everywhere (up to a finite number of points) and is continuous in $x_0$.

Comment: @Ufos: Yes, uniform convergence would let you conclude that.

Comment: @ArcticChar I oversimplified the statement, and missed that I was indeed using a uniform convergence. I tried to incorporate all the feedback, and fix inconsistencies. Can you check if the question now makes sense?

Comment: @Ufos: It looks like you have forgotten to add the hypothesis about uniform convergence. (The first you mention it is when you use it in the proof.)